# Map from $n$-sphere to $n$ dimensional torus

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $n\ge 2$. How can you prove that for every continuous $f:S^n\to T^n$, the induced map on singular homology $f_\star:H_n(S^n)\to H_n(T^n)$ is the zero map? Here, $S^n$ is the $n$ dimensional sphere, and $T^n=(S^1)^n$ is the $n$ dimensional torus.

I don't even know where to begin... This was on the final for my graduate course in algebraic topology. We've covered the fundamental group, covering spaces, and the basics for homology (simplicial complexes, Mayer-Viatoris, degree theory, etc). A hint in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is or was on the final?

Comment: Whoops, I meant _was_, the final is now over.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: for $n\geq 2$, the $n$-sphere $S^n$ is simply connected, and thus, any map $f:S^n\to T^n$ admits a lift to the universal cover of the torus, that is to say, there is a map $F:S^n\to \Bbb R^n$ such that $f=\pi\circ F$ where $\pi:\Bbb R^n\to T^n$ is the universal cover of the torus.

Comment: and then $f_\star=\pi_\star\circ F_\star$, but $F_\star=0$ since $H_n(\mathbb R^n)=0$. Thank you!

Comment: @MikeEarnest No problem : )

Comment: This is an old question, but so far all this tells us is $f_* = 0$. That a priori does not imply that $f$ is null homotopic, does it? (We only have the converse: that $f \simeq g \Longrightarrow f_* = g_*$ for maps $f, g : X \to Y$)

Comment: @DFord It doesn't but since the universal cover of the torus is contractible you can homotope the chosen lift of $f$ to a point, and the projection of this homotopy is a homotopy of the original map to a point. The OP doesn't ask for a homotopy of $f$ to a point, though, only to prove that $f$ is zero in homology.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, one could argue in the following way:

It holds for $n\ge2$
$$[S^n,T^n]=[S^n,K(\mathbb{Z},1)\times...\times K(\mathbb{Z},1)]\cong[S^n,K(\mathbb{Z},1)]^n\cong H^1(S^n,\mathbb{Z})^n=0,$$ so every map $S^n\rightarrow T^n$ is even nullhomotopic.

Comment: Doesn't Olivier's proof also show that $f$ is null-homotopic? Lift it to the universal cover, write down a null-homotopy there, then project the null-homotopy back down to $T^n$.

Comment: Yes, it does. My version does not give anything new and is just an alternative.

Comment: Thanks - just checking I wasn't missing something.